# How can I cancel a form submit from an angularjs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a validation directive that shows a message when form fields are invalid in a form. I would like to show the message and cancel the submit if the fields are not valid.
I have succeeded in showing the validation messages on submit by requiring the ngModel and form controllers but then I can't seem to find a way to use the FormController to cancel the form submit.
I have prepared a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eOoMPffobv56Nrec6xnl?p=preview) with my issue.
As you can see, it shows the error but I can't prevent the submit function from firing.

```js
// Code goes here

var directiveName = "fcValidate";
angular.module("app", [])
.directive(directiveName, ["$timeout", validatorDirective])
.controller("PageCtrl", [pageCtrl]);

function validatorDirective($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: ["^ngModel", "?^form"],
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
        var modelCtrl = controllers[0];
        var formCtrl = controllers[1];

        // Validation.
        $timeout(run);

        function run() {
            var requiredMessage = "Please enter the %(field)s.",
                minLengthMessage = "Sorry, but the %(field)s cannot be shorter than %(minLength)s characters.",
                maxLengthMessage = "Sorry, but the %(field)s cannot be longer than %(maxLength)s characters.",
                minValueMessage = "Sorry, but the %(field)s cannot be less than %(min)s.",
                maxValueMessage = "Sorry, but the %(field)s cannot be greater than %(max)s.",
                invalidNumberMessage = "Please ensure that the %(field)s is a valid number.";

            var content = null;
            var field = attributes.name;
            if (!field) {
                return;
            }

            var toWatch = function () {
                if (formCtrl) {
                    return formCtrl.$submitted;
                }
                return modelCtrl.$error;
            };

            scope.$watchCollection(toWatch, function (newValues, oldValues) {
                var error = modelCtrl["$error"];
                var invalid = modelCtrl["$invalid"];
                var dirty = modelCtrl["$dirty"];

                if ((formCtrl && !formCtrl.$submitted) || (!formCtrl && (_.keys(newValues) === _.keys(oldValues))) || !invalid || !dirty) {
                    return;
                }

                var msgTpl = null;
                var fieldName = attributes[directiveName];

                if (fieldName) {
                    fieldName = fieldName.toLowerCase();
                }

                if (error.required) {
                    msgTpl = requiredMessage;
                } else if (error.minlength) {
                    msgTpl = minLengthMessage;
                } else if (error.maxlength){
                    msgTpl = maxLengthMessage;
                } else if (error.min) {
                    msgTpl = minValueMessage;
                } else if (error.max){
                    msgTpl = maxValueMessage;
                } else if (error.number) {
                    msgTpl = invalidNumberMessage;
                }

                if (fieldName) {
                    var data = {
                        field: fieldName || "",
                        min: attributes.min,
                        max: attributes.max,
                        minLength: attributes.minlength,
                        maxLength: attributes.maxlength
                    };

                    if (msgTpl) {
                        content = _.string.sprintf(msgTpl, data);
                    } else {
                        content = fieldName;
                    }
                }
                
                // Show message...
                alert(content);
                // Cancel the form submit here...
            });
        }
    }
}

function pageCtrl() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.user = {};
  
  vm.submit = submit;
  
  function submit() {
    console.log(vm.user);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.string/2.3.0/underscore.string.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/angular.js"></script>
<body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="PageCtrl as vm">
  <form data-ng-submit="vm.submit()">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required="" minlength="2" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="vm.user.firstName" data-fc-validate="First Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

My question is, how can I cancel the form submit? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your complete directive code as well as sample html??

Comment: Sure thing. It's a lot of code though...

Comment: I've put all the code needed to run the directive.

Answer (score 0):

if it is like in jQuery, if you bind the function to a "submit" event you only need to `return false` in the callback.

Comment: it works as you implement it, after your check you could bind the submit event to a function that prevent its default behaviour, but winsik's solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Is disabling submit button enough for you? If yes, define name of form and then use it in ng-disabled on submit button

```
<form data-ng-submit="vm.submit()" name="validatingForm">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required="" minlength="2" placeholder="First Name" data-ng-model="vm.user.firstName" data-fc-validate="First Name" />
    <button type="submit" ng-disabled="validatingForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also I think ng-messages can be usefull for your validation messages - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages

Comment: I want a directive that can be reused with minimal code...hence the fcValidate directive. ngMessages seems to require verbose code for my purposes since I have many form inputs and many screens.

Comment: So I would try to pack ngmessages with predefined items into own directive.

Comment: Which means that the directive would only work for my one project which beats the purpose of making the directive. What I was looking for is a way to change the directive so that it can intercept the ngSubmit to run the callback function or cancel it.